# Mounting previous windows partition

Tags: 16.10

I have installed windows 10 in my laptop in C Drive. I have 3 more partitions (D, E and F). If i format C drive and install ubuntu will I be able to mount the previous windows partitions (d, e and f). 
If i can do , then how to do please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think why you won't be able to.
I have dualbooted Windows 8 with **Xubuntu** and **Windows** partions works fine on **Xubuntu**. I haven't tried what you asked but it 
*Other partions should work even on **Ubuntu**.

P.S.: I am not responsible for any loss of your data. Do wait for other answers.

Comment: i dont want to dual boot. I just want to format windows and use ubuntu. will i be able to use the other drives working with windows

Comment: I would recommend to first take backup of all needed files in *C:* like files in *Documents* and *Downloads* folder.

Comment: can i mount or not? how to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same one year ago using Ubuntu 16.04 and It worked fine. [Here, you can find how to mount the partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions).

**Note:** If you can back up the partitions and format them using ext4 file system, then you can have better Linux compatibility. For example, you can mount a partition as Home directory etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you will be able to do only in Windows, at least very easily as compared to Ubuntu. It seems to me that you're a beginner in using Ubuntu, so I would recommend not to format C drive and keep your Windows 10.

As for the partitions, you just have to click on the partition you want to mount in the Ubuntu file manager Nautilus and you're done. You can access those partitions straightaway. If not, there are two solutions I know.

1. Try this command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda*
   ```

   Replace '*' with the number of the partition. Install GParted to the know the partitions you want to mount with this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gparted
   ```

   Or find GParted in Ubuntu Software Center.
2. If this does not work, go to your Windows 10 and turn off Fast Startup. Control Panel> System and Security> Change what power buttons do (Under Battery icon sub-menu)> Turn off the Fast Startup.

The partitions in Windows 10 are NTFS type and for Linux we use Ext4 file system. Windows does not support Ext4 file system but Ubuntu will support NTFS file system. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the other partitions(D,E,F) are all NTFS partitions.If so,then to mount all these partitions,you can use the Disks Utility(Search for disks) in Ubuntu in order to mount these partitions for the current session or mount them everytime you log in to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly. Follow me:

1. Install Ubuntu from Live DVD/USB
2. While selecting disks, don't select the entire disk but, select 'Something Else'
3. Now at Disk Partition Manager, find the former C: drive and select it with mount as '/'
4. Also 'check' the 'format checkbox', format as Ext4
5. Go to every other partitions and select 'Do Not use this Partition' from the drop down list
6. If you want, you may create a Swap partition in the main C: drive
7. Install normally
8. Reboot to Ubuntu
9. You'll see the D:,E: and all other drives at the Unity Sidebar. Left Click them to access with the File manager.

You're with your new Ubuntu installation now!

Thanks :)